# Fish Shell: remapping VI-mode keybindings

Tags: fish

I want to remap some of the default movement bindings in fish's vi-mode (I'm using version 3.0). Specifically I want to change the `$` and `^` key mappings to be `E` and `B` respectively to match what I use in vim - but I cannot find any documentation on how to do this anywhere. Does anybody know how/if it is possible to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You should always specify which version of the program(s) you are using. Because in this case the preferred solution differs slightly between fish v2.x and v3.0. But in both cases it involves the `bind` command. So `man bind` is a good place to start.

Assuming you're using fish v2.x you'll want to create a function named `fish_user_key_bindings` in the file *~/.config/fish/functions/fish_user_key_bindings.fish*. You'll place your desired `bind` commands in that function. You'll find the default bindings in */usr/local/share/fish/functions/fish_vi_key_bindings.fish* (the directory might be different on your system). You'll want to add lines such as these to your *fish_user_key_bindings.fish* script:

```
function fish_user_key_bindings
    bind -m default \$ end-of-line
    bind -m default ^ beginning-of-line
end
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. I am using 3.0. Edited question.

Comment: My answer works with fish 3.0 as well although putting the `bind` commands in a `fish_user_key_bindings` function is no longer necessary. See https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/5191.

Comment: @kurtis, "no longer necessary", but if I have that function will I need to change it?

Comment: No need to change your use of *fish_user_key_bindings.fish*. The "no longer necessary" part of my answer simply alludes to the fact that in fish 3.0 you can define custom bindings without having to use that function. But that function is still supported.